# How do I insert the value of a PHP variable into javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to insert a value from php code into the page for use in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery1x.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
</script>
```

and this is PHP:

```
<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>
```

i need to insert here:

```
<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>assets/js/jquery1x.min.js
```

How can i do?

Thanks!

Comment: assuming that script tag is in a .php file already, just do exactly what you're doing.

Comment: What happens with the code you posted?

Comment: aahh! i can put it straight...right! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just simply echo it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>assets/js/jquery1x.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
</script>
```

And even if your code is separate file, you can still rename it to `.php` and include in html

```
<script src="file.php"></script>
```